# Best free online Pro Tools beginner tutorials

Tags: pro-tools, learning

I've started a one month trial of Pro Tools. As well as playing with it and learning, i'd also like to follow an online tutorial to help expand my knowledge and pick-up on what I'm missing.

Can anyone recommend a good free tutorial series?

Comment: I think YouTube is the obvious answer for that one ;)

Answer (score -1):

ProTools Expert channel in youtube is one I can recommend.